# Getting individual data from a <li> as text using BeautifulSoup Python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

This is a section of the HTML file i want to get data from.

```
<ul class="listing-key-specs ">
   <li>2002 (02 reg)</li>
   <li>Hatchback</li>
   <li>115,000 miles</li>
   <li>Manual</li>
   <li>1.8L</li>
   <li>123 bhp</li>
   <li>Petrol</li>
</ul>
```

This is how i extracted the `<ul>` from the rest of the document

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
vehicle_details = soup.find_all('ul', class_='listing-key-specs')
split_details = vehicle_details[2].get_text()
print (split_details)
```

From this line of code i get this output

```
 2002 (02 reg)
 Hatchback
 115,000 miles
 Manual
 1.8L
 123 bhp
 Petrol
```

However, what I want to do is to get each line from the output and put into a a list, so that the first line will be the first index and so on. But when I split the output by line break i get this output

```
 split_details = split_details.split('\n')
 ['', '2002 (02 reg)', 'Hatchback', '115,000 miles', 'Manual', '1.8L', '123 bhp', 'Petrol', '']
```

Which isn't what I want. Is there something I'm missing or is there another way to split this string into lines?

[This is the website](https://www.autotrader.co.uk/car-search?advertising-location=at_cars&search-target=usedcars&is-quick-search=true&radius=&onesearchad=used&onesearchad=nearlynew&onesearchad=new&make=&price-search-type=total-price&price-from=&price-to=&postcode=e14ns) if you're curious.

Comment: Just remove the first and last element from the list?

Comment: so those square brackets and commas are not part of the string

Comment: I see those extra characters are not part of the string they are just displayed in the terminal

Comment: You should really do some basic python coarses, that's called a list. It seperates all values by a comma if you print it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's best to use the [`stripped_strings`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string-generators) generator in this case. It holds all the strings inside a tag and its descendants, stripped of whitespace characters. An example,

```
html = '''<ul class="listing-key-specs ">
   <li>2002 (02 reg)</li>
   <li>Hatchback</li>
   <li>115,000 miles</li>
   <li>Manual</li>
   <li>1.8L</li>
   <li>123 bhp</li>
   <li>Petrol</li>
  </ul>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
vehicle_details = soup.find('ul', class_='listing-key-specs')
split_details = list(vehicle_details.stripped_strings)
print(split_details)
```

> ['2002 (02 reg)', 'Hatchback', '115,000 miles', 'Manual', '1.8L', '123 bhp', 'Petrol']

Or you could use `get_text` - strip and join by `', '` - but it will return a string instead of a list.

```
split_details = vehicle_details.get_text(', ', strip=True)
print(split_details)
```

> 2002 (02 reg), Hatchback, 115,000 miles, Manual, 1.8L, 123 bhp, Petrol

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list, you can use [list comprehension](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python)

```
html = '''<ul class="listing-key-specs ">
    <li>2002 (02 reg)</li>
    <li>Hatchback</li>
    <li>115,000 miles</li>
    <li>Manual</li>
    <li>1.8L</li>
    <li>123 bhp</li>
    <li>Petrol</li>
</ul>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
vehicle_details = [x.text for x in soup.find('ul', {'class': 'listing-key-specs'}).find_all('li')]
print(vehicle_details)
```

Output:

```
['2002 (02 reg)', 'Hatchback', '115,000 miles', 'Manual', '1.8L', '123 bhp', 'Petrol']
```

If you want the details in a single string, you can add this

```
vehicle_details_string = ', '.join(vehicle_details)
print(vehicle_details_string)
```

Output:

```
2002 (02 reg), Hatchback, 115,000 miles, Manual, 1.8L, 123 bhp, Petrol
```